# Padding with leading zeros in for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

Below are some relevant parts of a batch script I'm writing. I need it to loop through some numbers, pad them with leading zeros if necessary, and call a copy command using the padded value as part of a file name.

```
@ECHO ON
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
    set padded=000000%%i

    echo %SourceDir%\e20155*!padded:~-3!000.txt
    copy /b %SourceDir%\e20155*!padded:~-3!000.txt %CombinedDir%\seq%%i.txt2
)
```

This echoes: `C:\Users\user\Documents\American Community Survey\tracts_blockgroups\e20155*005000.txt`

But it runs: `copy /b C:\Users\user\Documents\American Community Survey\tracts_blockgroups\e20155*!~-3!000.txt D:\American Community Survey\tracts_blockgroups_combined\seq5.txt2`, which is obviously not what I want.

Why is this?

Comment: It looks like variable `padded` is empty, because then it expands to something like `~-3`. Anyway, in general I recommend to put quotes around both source and destination paths, and to use delayed expansion also for `SourceDir` and `CombineDir`...

Comment: Not quoting the directory was the problem, thanks. I was getting confused by what was being output by `@echo on`. I am not at all a batch file guy.

Comment: Perhaps not the answer, but you are going to need to quote the source and destination file names. copy /b `"%SourceDir%\e20155*!padded:~-3!000.txt" "%CombinedDir%\seq%%i.txt2"`

Comment: ...when I think over it, I believe you are talking about the command echo, which does not resolve delayed expansion, because it happens in an earlier command line parsing stage... are you sure it's `!~-3!` and not `!padded:~-3!`?

Comment: @lit, I'm afraid, that's what I already suggested... ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl - Yes, I was typing mine while you pressed Enter on your answer.